# How to count two differently sized Text Boxes on a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with many textboxes on it that are separately named and numbered. There two kinds of textbox, large ones and small ones. I've named all the large ones "Elevator 1" up to 12. I named the small ones "Riser 1" up to 20. I also have checkboxes linked to each textbox that makes the corresponding textbox disappear when it is unchecked. I'm trying to have a counter for each type of text box that counts how many textboxes are visible on the spreadsheet. The following code gives me an error saying, "Runtime Error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error". I've named the cell where the counter will appear "NumberOfRisers" and my worksheet is named "LobbyCars".

```
    Sub NumberOfRisers()

    Dim counter As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    counter = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count

    Worksheets("LobbyCars").Range(“NumberOfRisers”) = counter

    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: do you have textboxes on every sheet?  If not, remove the worksheet loop and only do the count on "LobbyCars".  Also rename your sub so there's no ambiguity with your named range (they are currently both named NumberOfRisers which might cause problems).  Also have your counter variables look at the specific sheet instead of ActiveSheet

Comment: Also, maybe it's just here on SO, but your quotes look funky. Try this `Worksheets("LobbyCars").Range("NumberOfRisers") = counter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `Function` that will count text boxes on a worksheet based on their name and visibility.

```
Private Function CountTextBoxes(txtBoxName As String, ws As Worksheet) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    If ws.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To ws.Shapes.Count
            With ws.Shapes(i)
                If .Type = msoTextBox And InStr(1, .Name, txtBoxName) And .Visible Then CountTextBoxes = CountTextBoxes + 1
            End With
        Next i
    End If

End Function

Sub CountMyTextBoxes()
    Debug.Print CountTextBoxes("Elevator", Sheets("Lobby Cars"))
    Debug.Print CountTextBoxes("Riser", Sheets("Lobby Cars"))
End Sub
```